# vaadin - exclude valo theme

Tags: sass, themes, vaadin8, vaadin-valo-theme

We don't have any usage of Valo theme. 
if we don't include valo in our custom theme, we got following error and our application load very slow.

How can we complete exclude valo theme? Thereby reduce css file size etc.

```
com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection
SEVERE: CSS files may have not loaded properly.
```

Comment: How do you exlcude Valo? Exception stack trace available?

Comment: i do not include valo in my custom theme mixin and don't import valo.

Comment: So there is no more error information than the 2 lines?

Comment: Are you sure your theme compiles without errors? You can try compiling it manually to get possible errors. [Theme compilation](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/themes/themes-compiling.html)